# Remove woocommerce products only from certain category parent ID

Tags: mysql, database, woocommerce, product

I am in need of some help writing a Mysql Query to remove `Woocommerce` products only from a certain parent category. The database contains over 20.000 products.

I found following query:

```
DELETE relations.*, taxes.*, terms.*
  FROM wp_term_relationships AS relations
  INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS taxes
    ON relations.term_taxonomy_id=taxes.term_taxonomy_id
  INNER JOIN wp_terms AS terms
    ON taxes.term_id=terms.term_id
  WHERE object_id IN (SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='product')
```

I need to link this with `wp_term_taxonomy` parent id `"7447"` so only products and custom fields matching this parent id will be removed.The structure has 3 levels of subcategories, is this even possible in mysql? Because I can't find any way to relate the subcategories directly to the parent category.

Forgive me for asking but i am not really good in MYSQL Queries. There is nothing online about the requirement. Besides I think it will be good to know for future developers facing this issue.

Many thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query did not remove products, only category information.. I ended up using:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-e-commerce-store-toolkit/

Wich does the job.... Will take like 24 hours but it does what it should, removing products and leaving category structure untouched!

Thx for the help Rahul!

Answer (score 0):

Verify the result first by using a `SELECT` statement like

```
SELECT relations.*, taxes.*, terms.*
  FROM wp_term_relationships AS relations
  INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS taxes
    ON relations.term_taxonomy_id=taxes.term_taxonomy_id
  INNER JOIN wp_terms AS terms
    ON taxes.term_id=terms.term_id
  WHERE object_id IN (SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='product')
  AND taxes.parent = 7447 <-- Add this extra condition
```

Comment: Hi thx, for your awnser and editing :) im currently uploading a test database but i am in Aruba, where internet is really slow :( .. I think this would not relate to any subcategories within the parrent? The structure contains a 3 level sub cats ?

Comment: @CoenPonsen, that I can't say without looking at table structure but yes, the above query will only get row(s) for which `parent_id = 7447` matches.

Comment: I guess I have to write a php script, i am currently looking for the native backend function .

Comment: @CoenPonsen, best suggestion I can give; try running the answered query and verify whether the result is as expected and then change it to delete statement.

Comment: @CoenPonsen, Not sure I understood your last comment.

Comment: I did the query and added on test product in a different category: 18617 products in db, result of query: 18616 I guess we have winner! Let me test this on final db to anwser as correct! Pls edit query: parent_id should be parent !